# IntelliJ Open module from desktop

Tags: intellij-idea, module

I have been using IntelliJ sparingly for the last six months and one thing always puzzles/annoys me.

Each module of IntelliJ  has a .iml folder in it's root. This .iml file is clearly recognized by IntelliJ it the file extension is associated with it during install.

Clicking on this .iml file I would expect the module to open up in IntellJ in the most recent project space. However, IntelleJ does not seem to want to do this, it has a popup saying the following.

Cannot open file:
No project to open file in.

So why can't intelliJ just open the module in the most recently used project space. Instead I have to go to great lengths to open a project space and then import the project which is so unproductive. Often I have to look open and inspect several projects an hour and as is, the process is onerous.

Am I missing something, or is there really no way to open projects directly from the desktop/file explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Click the file which has .ipr extension to open it in intellij, and you can see it in the most recent project space after it is opened.

- The *.iml file describes modules. It includes module paths, dependencies, order settings, etc. A project may contain multiple *.iml files.
- The *.ipr file stores settings related to a project in general, for example, paths to modules and module libraries, compiler and configurations, entry points, etc.

You can find more detail in [IntelliJ IDEA Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp10.5/project.html)